# Passing jpg file directly on from backend server

Tags: ruby, heroku, sinatra

I'm uploading an image file from my app via JSON to my ruby backend hosted by Heroku. It is then supposed to be passed to stripe via their gem via a path to my uploaded image. Is it possible to just pass it the tempfile? The stripe docs say to do:

```
Stripe::FileUpload.create(
  :purpose => 'dispute_evidence',
  :file => File.new('/path/to/a/file.jpg')
)
```

my backend post looks like:

```
post '/account/id' do
    tempfile = params[:file][:tempfile]
    filename = params[:file][:filename]
    path = "#{tempfile.path}/#{filename}"

    p path      -->    "/tmp/RackMultipart20170112-4-fgtv2n/photoID.jpg"

    begin
        file = Stripe::FileUpload.create({
                :purpose => params[:purpose],
                :file => File.new(path)
            },
            {
                :stripe_account => params[:stripe_account]
            }
        )
    rescue Stripe::StripeError => e
        status 402
        return "Error saving verification id to account: #{e.message}"
    end
    status 200
    return file.to_json
end
```

but when running i get:

```
Errno::ENOENT - No such file or directory @ rb_sysopen - /tmp/RackMultipart20170112-4-1qmr03y/photoID.jpg:
```

i cant figure out what im doing wrong. can any one help or suggest a better option?

Comment: Is it possible to pass base64 image instead ulr? If possible then convert your image to base64  and send to server where you can create image file using that data.

Comment: even though heroku prevents file system writes, you can still write tempfiles.  I wonder if it would work to copy it to a new tempfile and pass that path

Comment: how would i write params[:file] to tmp?

Answer (score 0):

You are mistaking `tempfile` for a directory. `tempfile` is actually your temporary file, so pass it instead of `path` (that you don't need any more).